# Rim raf / jenkins- syntaxError : Unexepected token . in ignore-enonent.js

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm-install

Hi on Monday all of our jenkins builds started failing on npm install on the rim raf ignore.enonent.js file

I can see that rim raf did publish a new version 7days ago but the ignore-enonent.js file has always been like this.

Anyone else seeing this issue?

`Server\DPAWebUI\Verint.DPA.FrontEnd\node_modules\rimraf\dist\cjs\src\ignore-enoent.js:15
if (er?.code !== 'ENOENT') {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .'`

`Note this issue only started after the weekend.  I tried running npm install without  jenkins and no issues. The issue only seems to occur when run from jenkins`

Answer (score 1):

I got this too - only in jenkins as well :D

Found in the end that it was related to the recent rimraf release 4.1.2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf?activeTab=versions.

I have grunt (v3) defined in my package json so local build works fine. But in Jenkins i have a pipeline script which was explicitly installing the latest version of grunt, which then brought in this incompatible dependency and broke stuff...

So in your Jenkins pipeline make sure you are not installing grunt (or whatever is using rimraf - check using `npm ls rimraf`) and make sure the version of rimraf/parent of rimraf is the same on Jenkins. Can add `npm ls rimraf` in your Jenkins pipeline script as a debug line to figure out if its using a different version.